# mysql 8 performance optimization

Tags: mysql-8.0

here is my configuration.
Database size is around 160GB.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Tumengerel, there is a setting called innodb_dedicated_server that you should check out.  It basically allocates 3/4 total system memory to your database engine and handles 4 important settings like buffer log and log flush automatically.  Also, there is a great book called 'High Performance MySQL' that is easy to read and goes over best practices in detail for mysql, specifically INNODB.

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/innodb-dedicated-server.html